# Webcam is not even opening OpenCV is just printing the output

Tags: python, opencv

I have created an OpenCV function by following some tutorials which captures 100 frames from my webcam and store it in a path that I have mentioned, but when I tried to check if webcam is correctly integrated with OpenCV or not 
I have run this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is working perfectly fine i can see myself in gray frame

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load HAAR face classifier
face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Load functions
def face_extractor(img):
    # Function detects faces and returns the cropped face
    # If no face detected, it returns the input image

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 3)

    if faces is ():
        return None

    # Crop all faces found
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    return cropped_face

# Initialize Webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# ret, frame = cap.read()
count = 0

# Collect 100 samples of your face from webcam input
while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(type(frame))
    print(frame.shape)
#     if ret==True:
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
        count += 1
        face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Save file in specified directory with unique name
        file_name_path = r'C:\Users\madhumani\path\\' + str(count) + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

        # Put count on images and display live count
        cv2.putText(face, str(count), (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Face Cropper', face)

    else:
        print("Face not found")

#     else:
#         print("no camera")
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 or count == 100: #13 is the Enter Key
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()      
print("Collecting Samples Complete")
```

according to that tutorial the webcam should capture 100 frames of that particular person and store it in a path but instead im just getting `face not found` printed as output

Here is the output:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(480L, 640L, 3L)
Face not found
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(480L, 640L, 3L)
Face not found
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(480L, 640L, 3L)
Face not found
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(480L, 640L, 3L)
Face not found
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(480L, 640L, 3L)
Face not found
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works without an error. Somehow the method `face_extractor` returns `None` in your case. Can you share the result of `print(len(faces))` called above the line `if faces is ()`. If it is 0 something is wrong with the classifier.

Comment: @Bhoke 0 is the output

Comment: then what could be wrong with the classifier ??

Comment: I suspect that your xml file could be corrupted. Also you can try to add lines `cv2.imshow('window',gray)` and `cv2.waitKey()` to the same location above in order to see how frames are acquired.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working and it writes the files to the specified path. I think the only thing you are missing is that given path `C:\Users\madhumani\path\` does not exist and you should create the directory first.

You can create directory by adding following code:

```
import os
dir = r'C:\Users\madhumani\path\\'
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

or create it manually.

Comment: no you took me wrong the issue isnt about the path but  when  i run the code, the code isnt opening webcam and starts capturing me

Comment: Haha I read only "but instead im just getting face". I will edit the answer as I solve it.